# Can I be sure a Word document is safe if it doesn't have macros

Tags: malware, microsoft, office

I am aware that MS Word documents can be potentially dangerous due to the executable macros contained within them.

But for a particular document, I have opened the macros and can see there are none. Can I be sure, therefore, that this document is not malicious?

Answer (score 4):

Macros is the major risk associated with word documents. But it is not the only one.

It is possible that there is some sort of code execution vulnerability in Word, that allows a malicous word document to spread malware on your computer. Such a vulnerability would be a pretty big deal, though, and personally I would not worry about it.

Is there a way to make Word documents make HTTP requests? I am not sure, but if there is, the risk would be similar to clicking on a link on a webpage.

The content of the word document could also be used for social engineering, but here it is you rather than Word that might be vulnerable.

Personally, I open word documents without macros from untrusted sources without thinking twice about it.

(A side note: If you have opened the word document to check for macros, you have already exposed yourself to risk. For the modern MS Office file formats, you can use the extensions to check for macros - `.docx` does not allow macros, while `.dotm` do.)

Comment: I guess you should add a warning that this applies only if Office is kept up-to-date, otherwise it might be vulnerable to publicly known exploits which are worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

The only malicious use of Word docs other than VB macros I've come across is phishing. I've seen plenty of word docs made to look like there's some gated content that requires you to click on a URL in the doc and sign in to access that content. It tends to look pretty hammy, but it'll catch out some users.